# Getting the location distance in a multi request

Tags: foursquare

In trying to get a list of foursquare venues by id, I ended up using the multi endpoint.

However, the venues returned do not have a distance value from my current lat long

So, as an example I can use the venue endpoint

- https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/43f9b9aaf964a520d12f1fe3?ll=47.62330382444445,-122.33604573666668
- This will return a venue which has a distance value

However, trying to do the same using the multi endpoint

- https://api.foursquare.com/v2/multi?requests=/venues/43f9b9aaf964a520d12f1fe3,/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3&ll=47.62330382444445,-122.33604573666668
- This **does not** return a distance value

Any idea how to use the lat long parameter on a multi request? 
I couldn't find much documentation on this

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the "ll" parameter as part of each of the requests listed out in "requests". Currently, the "ll" parameter is being interpreted as an argument to the "multi" endpoint, when you actually want it to be a parameter on each of the two "venues" requests.

You should URL encode the both of the full requests (including the ll parameter) and set that as the value of the "requests" parameter.